# How to make a float view all over the other applications in jailbroken iOS environment?

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak, uiwindow, tweak

My tweak needs a float view all over the other applications, looks like a HUD view, I tried to make a `UIWindow` with `UIWindowLevelAlert` inside `SpringBoard`, this view shows rightly, but it blocks all the touch events, the apps below are freezing  and cannot respond any touching. How can I make it show but pass through touch events?

Key part of my code:

```
_window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
_window.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
_window.opaque = NO;
_window.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert;
_window.rootViewController = self;
[_window setHidden:NO];
```

Comment: have you tried disabling user interaction?

Comment: @Aris Yes, I tried, but doesn't work.